# Meanings of ".1", "@" and "*" in Mac OS library file names

Tags: macos, ls

I am working with two library files on Mac OS.  Here are how they look like when I use `ls`

```
libmkl_rt.1.dylib*            
libmkl_rt.dylib@
```

i have three questions on the file names:

1. What does ".1" mean?
2. What does "*" mean?
3. What does "@" mean?

Comment: Dude, read https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ls&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+12.2-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html

Comment: You probably have aliased the `ls` command to add something like its `-F` option, which adds a suffix to filenames indicating the file's type/permissions/whatever. Use `alias ls` to see how it's defined, then `man ls` to see what the option does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what the `.1` means, but I believe `*` means executable, and `@` means symbolic link, given a thread found on the Unix StackExchange, see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/96132